# Why does EF Core join the same table multiple times on the same key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

We are using `.NET Core 3.1`, [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.9) and [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/3.1.4). We have the following database models:

`Testrunconfig.cs`

```cs
[Table("testrunconfig", Schema = "fit")]
public partial class Testrunconfig
{
    public Testrunconfig()
    {
        Testruntestgrp = new HashSet<Testruntestgrp>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("product_id")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Column("configfilename")]
    [StringLength(512)]
    public string Configfilename { get; set; }
    [Column("started")]
    public DateTime? Started { get; set; }
    [Column("finished")]
    public DateTime? Finished { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProductId))]
    [InverseProperty("Testrunconfig")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Testrunconfig")]
    public virtual ICollection<Testruntestgrp> Testruntestgrp { get; set; }
}
```

`Testruntestgrp.cs`

```cs
[Table("testruntestgrp", Schema = "fit")]
public partial class Testruntestgrp
{
    public Testruntestgrp()
    {
        
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("testrunconfig_id")]
    public int? TestrunconfigId { get; set; }
    [Column("status")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [Column("testname")]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Testname { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TestrunconfigId))]
    [InverseProperty("Testruntestgrp")]
    public virtual Testrunconfig Testrunconfig { get; set; }
}
```

`Product.cs`

```cs
[Table("product", Schema = "fit")]
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Testrunconfig = new HashSet<Testrunconfig>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("name")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Product")]
    public virtual ICollection<Testrunconfig> Testrunconfig { get; set; }
}
```

`TestExecutionHelper.cs` helper class:

```cs
public class TestExecutionHelper
{
    public Testrunconfig TestrunConfig { get; set; }
    public bool TestSelected { get; set; }
    public string SelectedTestName { get; set; }
    public string FinalResult { get; set; }
}
```

We have the following query in C# code:

```cs
private static string GetFinalResult(Testrunconfig trc)
{
    if (trc == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (trc.Finished == null)
    {
        return "NOT FINISHED";
    }

    bool error = trc.Testruntestgrp?.Any(x => x.Status != "OK") ?? true;
    return error ? "ERROR" : "OK";
}

private void TestFunction()
{
    string configuration = "config_123";
    string testName = "test_123";

    var test = _fitDbContext.Testrunconfig
        .Include(x => x.Testruntestgrp)
        .Include(x => x.Product)
        .Where(x => x.Configfilename == configuration)
        .Where(x => x.Testruntestgrp.Select(y => y.Testname).Contains(testName))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
        .Select(x => new TestExecutionHelper()
        {
            TestrunConfig = x,
            TestSelected = testSelected,
            SelectedTestName = testName,
            FinalResult = GetFinalResult(x),
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

When I call `TestFunction()`, the following SQL query is generated:

```sql
SELECT t.id, t.product_id, t.configfilename, t.started, t.finished, p.id, p.description, p.name, t0.id, t0.testrunconfig_id, t0.status, t0.testname, t1.id, t1.testrunconfig_id, t1.status, t1.testname
FROM fit.testrunconfig AS t
INNER JOIN fit.product AS p ON t.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN fit.testruntestgrp AS t0 ON t.id = t0.testrunconfig_id
LEFT JOIN fit.testruntestgrp AS t1 ON t.id = t1.testrunconfig_id
WHERE (t.configfilename = @__configuration_0) AND @__testName_1 IN (
    SELECT t2.testname
    FROM fit.testruntestgrp AS t2
    WHERE t.id = t2.testrunconfig_id
)
ORDER BY t.id DESC, p.id, t0.id, t1.id
```

Why is `LEFT JOIN fit.testruntestgrp ON t.id` performed twice?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is your OrderBy call that is confusing things. I'm not sure what type X projects to in the Linq expression but you can see that in SQL it is ordering by all Ids, which doesn't seem correct. Can you order after the select only on the column that is relevant?

Comment: Look at [Split queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries)

Comment: `Why is LEFT JOIN fit.testruntestgrp ON t.id performed twice?` - Perhaps this is a flaw in the Npgsql provider. In my personal experience, some EF queries that were processed at lightning speed in Sql Server worked for a very long time in Postgresql due to inefficient generated sql.

Comment: To me it looks like `Npgsql` isn't aware that `trc.Testruntestgrp` collection in `GetFinalResult(Testrunconfig trc)` was already populated by `Include(x => x.Testruntestgrp)` inside `TestFunction()`. Therefore, it tries to include it again, although it wouldn't need to.

Comment: Everything looks correct. You have Eager Loading query, so do not expect one-to-one SQL translation. If you do not need `Testruntestgrp` navigation property in result - do not include.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I don't need `Testruntestgrp` in the final result, but I expect it to be populated inside `GetFinalResult(Testrunconfig trc)` so I can perform some logic.

Comment: Then query is valid and generated SQL is as designed.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Can you please explain why `LEFT JOIN fit.testruntestgrp ON t.id` is needed twice? Wouldn't it be much more efficient if `JOIN` was performed only once? I believe the result would be the same.

Comment: Eager Loading has no analogue in the SQL. EF Core make special query for retrieving Collection navigation property along with main entity. Try `AsSplitQuery()` and you will be surprised.

Comment: Unfortunately, `AsSplitQuery()` was introduced in EF Core 5.0 ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#split-queries-1)). We are using EF Core 3.1.9 as stated in the question.

Comment: First Eager Loading query `TestrunConfig = x`, second `FinalResult = GetFinalResult(x)`. And yes they can optimize that and probably they did that in EF Core 6 +

Comment: Cross-posted on Github as https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28312